# Solution to puzzle #7 in MATH | Riddles and puzzles

Tags: mathematics

The screenshot below os from the app [Math riddles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BlackGames.MathRiddles&hl=en_US&gl=US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dgoogle+play+math+riddles&pcampaignid=APPU_1_erVJY4uGO4b6qwG-iqi4BQ).

[image]

My first guess was 10, since 2×2+1=5 then 3×3+1=10. Alternatively 11, since 3×3+(3-1). Or maybe 12 because of the number of intersections with 3 or 4 lines.

However, the "correct" answer is

> 14

Can anyone explain why this should be the/a correct solution?

Comment: Frankly, you can't infer a rule from from just one example.  You could say 5 because always 5.  Or 6 because it comes after 5.  This is a "guess what I think" question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Count the number of squares in each of the diagrams.

General solution:

> For a $n\times n$ square, we will have $n^2$ squares of size $1$, $(n-1)^2$ squares of size $2$, and so on. Then, the total number of squares is:$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\boxed{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}$$

Comment: Horrible question, since there are multiple correct answers but no multiple choice to weed them out.